# is it still early to adopt html5?

Tags: html

I'm working on a new project, it is a wordpress theme with advanced functionality. I can't think of any reason to start using html5 but a personal curiosity.

Is it too early?

Comment: I still look for alternatives of HTML 5 and CSS3 everytime i need one. IE5-7 is still widely used.

Comment: belongs on http://webmasters.stackexchange.com
Q&A for pro webmasters

Answer (score 0, accepted):

There was an extensive browser test in 2009 which found that [HTML5 semantic tags work in very nearly all browsers](http://www.stevefenton.co.uk/Content/Blog/Date/200907/Blog/HTML-5-Browser-Test/).

Martin Beeby has also written an article on [whether adopting HTML5 is right for you](http://blogs.msdn.com/b/thebeebs/archive/2012/01/02/html5-how-to-decide-if-it-s-right-for-you.aspx).

In essence, most advice points towards using HTML5 (bearing in mind the first draft just documents what browsers already do) but not relying entirely on some of the emerging bits until they are stable. It isn't a black-and-white decision, but that's why people rely on Internet professionals to help them to decide.

Answer (score 0):

It's not too early to start using it, although you possibly should not use all features. To make your site compatible with non-HTML 5 browser, you should look at using something like [modernizr](http://modernizr.com). Their site will tell you which features they can introduce into non-HTML 5 browser and which they can't. But this is a good way to get started.